# Why isn't my view rendering when called from ajax.post in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

so, I built a view with a ViewResult and the View has a text box to enter a search string and a button to submit. It works great, it return my searched items and displays on the screen. Now, my requirement is to move that text box to the home layout (below) and submit from there. But, when I press submit and it calls the ajax post, the debug shows the search string searching the viewResult and it even gets to the View associated, but the View does not render. any ideas?

Here is the the Search Box

```
<div style="float:right;">
                <input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" />
                <a href="#" id="search" ><img src="~/Images/Custom/searchIcon.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"/></a>
            </div>
```

Here is the javascript with the ajax post

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#search").click(function () {
            var searchString = $("#searchString").val();
            var datastring = { "searchString": searchString };

            $.ajax({

                url: "/Home/Search/",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(datastring),
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    console.log('success!!');
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my ViewResult:

```
   public ViewResult Search(string searchString, int? pageNumber)
    {
      //  var searchString = fc["searchString"];
        var results = new ArrayList();
        var mylist = new List<SearchResult>();
        var model = new SearchViewModel();
        var host = "/CommunityWildlifeHabitat";
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
            host = "";


            // Search Communities
            var search = from s in db.Communities
                         where s.ComunityName.Contains(searchString) || s.Description.Contains(searchString)
                         select s;

            // Search Resource Center
            var docs = from d in db.ResourceCenters
                       where d.Title.Contains(searchString) || d.Description.Contains(searchString)
                       select d;

        // Set up Arraylist with type Community
        foreach(var c in search)
        {
            var community = new SearchResult();
            community.type = "community";
            community.CommunityId = c.CommunityId;
            community.CommunityName = c.ComunityName;
            community.Description = c.Description;
            community.CommunityType = c.CommunityType1.TypeName;
            community.CommunityCity = c.CommunityCity;
            community.CommunityState = c.CommunityState;
            community.CommunityZip = c.CommunityZip;
            community.Population = c.Population;
            mylist.Add(community);
        }

        // Set up ArrayList with type ResourceCenter
        foreach (var d in docs)
        {
            var document = new SearchResult();
            document.type = "document";
            document.Title = d.Title;
            document.Document_Description = d.Description;
            document.FilePath = d.FilePath;
            document.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(d.Date);
            document.UpLoadedBy = d.UpLoadedBy;
            mylist.Add(document);
        }

        model.results = mylist;
        ViewBag.results = model.results;
        ViewBag.searchString = searchString;
        ViewBag.Host = host;

        return View(mylist.ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10));
    }
```

Lastly, here is my View:

```
<h2>Search</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.searchString as string, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required"})
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
    <hr />



    if (@Model.Count != 0)
    {
        <h3>The following results were found for @ViewBag.searchString</h3>


        foreach (var search in @Model)
        {

            if (@search.type == "community")
            {
                <div class="resource-element">
                    <a href="@ViewBag.Host/Communities/CommunityPage/@search.CommunityId">
                        <span class="resource-type pull-right">Community</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="@ViewBag.Host/Communities/CommunityPage/@search.CommunityId"><h3>@search.CommunityName</h3></a>
                    <p>@search.Description</p>
                    <span class="">Type : @search.CommunityType</span><br />
                    <span class="">@search.CommunityCity, @search.CommunityState @search.CommunityZip</span><br />
                    <span class="">Population: @search.Population</span>
                    <br>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {


                <div class="resource-element">
                    <a href="@ViewBag.Host@search.FilePath">
                        <span class="resource-type pull-right">Document</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="@ViewBag.Host@search.FilePath"><h3>@search.Title</h3></a>
                    <p>@search.Document_Description</p>
                    <span class="">@search.Date</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="">@search.UpLoadedBy</span>
                    <br>
                </div>
            }

        }

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("Search", "Home", new { searchString = @ViewBag.searchString, pageNumber }),
            new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })

    }
    else
    {
        if (@ViewBag.searchString != null)
        {
            <div class="resource-element">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="resource-type pull-right"></span>
                </a>
                <h3>No Results Found</h3>
            </div>
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to manually trigger the rendering. So try replacing `success: function () { console.log('success!!'); }` with the js function that can render the view. If no such function exists in your IDE, you'll have to insert it manually into the DOM.

Comment: yeah, I have considered that. thanks

Comment: If you tag this as C# mvc or as ASP mvc, (I'm guess ting this is c#, but not 100% sure) you might get answers from there as well.

Comment: Everything seems in order here, except that on success you're simply writing to the console - is there a specific div that the results should be rendered into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply change your form helper with the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
```

and remove your jquery, it should post your form correctly to the server, and automatically reload the page.

There is no specific need in running an async call inside your page.